# Toad run create function in oracle

Tags: oracle, function, toad

I'm trying to create a simple function in Oracle using Toad, but when you run the script, it shows me an error message or success.

My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION simple RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

BEGIN
  RETURN 'Simple Function';
END simple;
/
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is correct, you can try with F5.

**v6 - v8.6**

- Execute Statement (Editor contains 1 statement)  --  F9 Execute
- Statement at Cursor  --  SHIFT F9 Execute
- Multiple Statements  --  F5
- Compile PL/SQL Object at Cursor  --     F9
- Compile All PL/SQL in Tab  --  Not Possible

**v9**

- Execute Statement (Editor contains 1 statement)  --  F9
- Execute Statement at Cursor  --  F9 (with delimiters) or SHIFT F9 (w/o delimiters)
- Execute Multiple Statements  --  F5
- Compile PL/SQL Object at Cursor  --  F9
- Compile All PL/SQL in Tab  --  Mouse Right-Click in Navigator
  “Compile All”

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This also may help:

```
DECLARE
  v_retVal Varchar2(20);
--
  FUNCTION simple RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN 'Simple Function';
  END simple;
BEGIN
  v_retVal:= simple;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_retVal);
END;
/
```